# how to use a variable name within dplyr::lead/lag function

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a tibble in which I want to lag/lead various columns and check their correlations.
Currently, for every column name, I have to have a separate function to do the lead/lag and correlation function.
Is there a way in which I could pass the column name as a variabe and then use that variable with lag/lead

```
#This is what I have tried unsuccessfully so far

library(janitor)
library(tidyverse)

(x <- mtcars %>% 
    as_tibble())

var_to_lag <- "carb"    

# Tried without success
x %>% mutate(lag_var = lag(!!var_to_lag, 1))
x %>% mutate(lag_var = lag(contains(var_to_lag), 1))
x %>% mutate(lag_var = lag(vars(contains(var_to_lag)), 1))
x %>% mutate(lag_var = lag(vars(!!var_to_lag), 1))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `mutate_at` which accepts string input

```
library(dplyr)
x %>%  mutate_at(vars(var_to_lag), list(lag_var = ~lag(.)))
```

We can also use `get`

```
x %>% mutate(lag_var = lag(get(var_to_lag)))
```

Or first convert `var_to_lag` to symbol (`sym`) and then evaluate (`!!`)

```
x %>% mutate(lag_var = lag(!!sym(var_to_lag)))
```